# Automapper based convertion from Datatable to generic type not working

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.5, automapper

I am using Automapper to convert a data table to a generic type. This is my code

```
    public T MapTo<T>(DataTable table)
    {
        if (table == null || table.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(table.CreateDataReader())[0], typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

My Data table has got 13 columns and so does the type I am mapping it to, however I still get an error in the else block above as :

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at MySolution.GenericMap.MapTo[T](DataTable table)

What could be wrong? I am using Automapper 4.1.1.0 and .Net 4.5

Comment: Seems to be broken. Check out this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/715, https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/835

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess its time to dump Automapper and go with a pure reflection based approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be broken in Automapper versions 4.0.0+ (see [bug report](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/715))

This linked [bug report](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/835) suggests to downgrade to version 3.3.1 or to use the following procedure:

> There should be living the DataReaderMapper. I have extracted an old version from The DataReaderMapper (from Version 3.1) and Registered it and now it works.
>
> **Register Mapper:**
>
> MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new DataReaderMapper());
>
> **Code of DataReaderMapper:**
>
> https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v3.3.1/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/DataReaderMapper.cs
>
> **Following Code has to be changed:**
>
> `TypeMap typeMap = configurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(context.SourceValue, context.DestinationValue, context.SourceType, destinationElementType);`
>
> New Code:
>
> `Map typeMap = configurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(context.SourceType, destinationElementType);`
>
> And
>
> ```
> if (context.TypeMap == null)
>     {                
>         throw new AutoMapperMappingException(context, "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.");
>     }
> ```
>
> To
>
> ```
> if (context.TypeMap == null)
>         {                
>             return;
>         }
> ```

While the previous procedure works the [bug report](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/715) also links to a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper.data) with code for the old DataReaderMapper but it didn't work with DynamicMap on my machine.